# Mapster: how to instantiate an interface field with a specific implemetation?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mapster

For example I have ObjectA:

```
public class ObjectA {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
}
```

and ObjectB:

```
public class ObjectB {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IDataUserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map ObjectA to ObjectB. `IDataUserInfo` is an interface and there is an implementation for this interface called `DataUserInfo`. Both `UserInfo` from ObjectA and ObjectB have absolutely the same structure.

But after I call:

```
instanceOfObjectA.Adapt<ObjectB>();
```

I see that the actual type of the `UserInfo` field is `GeneratedType_1`. This is expected because our mapster doesn't know anything about our implementation of the `IDataUserInfo` interface.

How can I tell Mapster to use a specific implementation when materializing `IDataUserInfo` interface? I tried the following config but it still shows `GeneratedType_1` instead of `DataUserInfo`:

```
public class MappingConfig : IRegister
{
    public void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        config.NewConfig<ObjectA, ObjectB>()
            .Map(dest => dest.UserInfo, src => new DataUserInfo { Field1 = src.UserInfo.Field1, ... });
    }
}
```